# Using Find-Union data structure in an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, union-find

I'm trying to solve the following algorithmic problem:

Let's say that we have a data structure that allows us to insert elements and delete and write the minimum element. And let's suppose that we know a sequence of `n` commands, all of which are either `I(k)` (insert k) or `D` (delete the minimum and output it).

Our task is to decide for each `D` command which number it will return. For instance, for the sequence:

```
I(2) D I(5) I(4) I(3) D D I(1) D D
```

the result ought to be

```
2 3 4 1 5
```

The goal (or a hint) is to achieve better than `O(nlog(n))` complexity, using a Find-Union data structure which allows us to do `n` make-sets, finds and unions in `O(na(n))`, where `a(n)` is the inverse Ackermann function.

This is not homework - I'm preparing for an exam and am having a difficulty with this exercise for more than a couple of hours already.

I would appreciate any further hints

**Edit:** I forgot to add one crucial assumption. All numbers we insert are from range  1..n

**Further edit:** it turns out that I'm not the first one to encounter that problem; it's called the **off-line minimum problem** and, anyone interested, can do some further reading [here](http://llhuii.is-programmer.com/posts/31126.html)

Comment: Unsure whether this observation is useful, but sometimes constraints help creativity: it is clear that the commands `I(k1) I(k2) ... I(kn) D D D ... D` amounts to sorting `k1` through `kn`, which cannot be done in faster than `O(n log(n))` using only comparisons. So at some point you are going to have to do some operation on keys that does *not* look like comparison.

Comment: @DanielWagner `Edit: I forgot to add one crucial assumption. All numbers we insert are from range 1..n`. This relaxes the bound of general case sorting

Comment: Not sure how a union-find data structure can help reduce the time complexity ! Did you come up with this question ?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense to me.  This is exactly the type of situation where a priority queue is the appropriate tool. That would give you O(n log n) complexity.  It is not clear what trick or loophole in the problem statement is supposed to make a union-find data structure more efficient.

Comment: @amit I saw that assumption. My observation stands: you are somehow going to have to exploit the extra structure given by that assumption -- that is, to repeat myself, "at some point you are going to have to do some operation on keys that does _not_ look like comparison". I'm not sure what that operation might be, though, or else I would have written up an answer!

Comment: Thank you all for the hints; it turns out that this problem is somewhat popular and is called the `off-line minimum problem`. You can find some elaboration here: http://llhuii.is-programmer.com/posts/31126.html

Comment: It's not the same problem if you say that numbers are taken from the set [1...n]. You should state that every number is inserted exactly once !